# Rails many-to-many with "global" option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, many-to-many

I am working on a multi-site blog in rails. My data model looks something like:

```
Site
has_many :postings
has_many :posts, through: :postings


Post
has_many :postings
has_many :sites, through: :postings

Posting
belongs_to :site
belongs_to :post
```

I'm trying to figure out the best way to mark a Post as "global" so any Site, including ones created in the future, can access the post. Right now, Post has a global boolean attribute and I have an after_create callback on the Site model that loops through all the global Posts and creates a Posting to add it to the new site. This works decently well as it allows me to easily query for site.posts, but I have a feeling there must be a better way to do it that avoids the need for the after_create callback. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This gem seems to do what I wanted: https://github.com/brianhempel/active_record_union

```
# site.rb
def all_posts
  Post.where(global: true).union(posts.where(posts: { global: false }))
end
```